# Non-android, non-ios, non-web apps

Tags: facebook, post, device

We plan to manufacture a device that we want it to communicate with Facebook. If the user presses a button on the device, we want something to appear on users wall as a post. It means that the device will post on behalf of the user on Facebook.

As we see from the Facebook developer page, the types of applications are a Facebook app, a web app or a mobile app. The thing we have just explained does not belong to any of these categories. For instance, it is not a web app because the device does only support http connection but does not have a built-in web browser. It is not an Andorid or iOs app because the operating system in this device is none of these.

What would you suggest for this kind of application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely look into http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/

Your other decent option would be to run an HTTP server on your device that users could connect to from a computer or phone to authenticate.

Once authorized, a simple HTTP request is all that it will take to share anything.

Edit: Just noticed that Facebook is no longer accepting applications for new partners with the auth device pattern. This is definitely what you want. You could try contacting them anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Answer = make it web app but dont forget the facebook policies about the user privacy issues. Your device can send a signal to your server and server can make the post i think it is possible (hmmm but to acquire access token again your clients have to login your webapp again every 60 days, there must be a better solution)

I am also working on similar problem

I have a prototype device for jogging wrist band and I am trying to post a wall story about number of steps in current day and the tempo on behalf of a user by just clicking on a button on the machine when it is connected to wlan or android phone in a wireless fashion.